# Postgres hangs when a possible null column value is used in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to mash some user data from several tables together in Postgres in order to display information in a table on a web page. Users may or may not have "contact" information, and I'm trying to include the "contact" email address as part of what gets returned in the select query.

The query I'm using boils down to the following:

```
select u.user_id, r.role_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, c.email, o.state_active, ce.name  
from user  
join user_role r on u.user_id = r.user_id
join company c on r.company_id = c.company_id  
join object_state o on u.state_id = o.state_id  
left outer join user_contact uc on u.user_id = uc.user_id and uc.default_flag = 'Y' and uc.status = 'A'  
left outer join contact c on uc.contact_id = c.contact_id and c.contact_type like 'E%'
```

I keep running into problems around the outer joined tables at the bottom. It appears that if I do a SELECT * sort of query, I'll get back everything I expect, but as soon as I run the above query, the statement just hangs and never returns values. If, however, I remove the c.email portion of the select statement, everything returns quickly with no problems at all.

Am I missing some sort of core feature of Postgres where I'm unable to select a column that might be null, or is there something else obvious that I'm completely missing as far as this query goes? I don't understand why it works fine if I don't require the email, but not otherwise.

Comment: How much data do you have in these tables? Are they properly indexed?

Comment: user and user_contact tables ~80k, contact table ~230k. Those would be the big ones. Looking back now, it appears contact doesn't have any indexes whatsoever, but it's basically a dump of emails, phones, physical addresses, etc. I'm not sure how an index would help a catch-all table like that exactly.

Comment: Could you include details about the schema of the tables in the query? Could you also define what you mean by "Postgres hangs"? Does the query eventually complete?

Comment: I could get pertinent schema details if absolutely necessary, but there's a lot to it. I've allowed the query to run for over three minutes without returning when including c.email in the select statement. I have yet to see it run to completion. Removing c.email allows the query to return in under five seconds.

Comment: Anything involved in a `JOIN` needs indexes on the columns you're joining against. This means `user_id` and so forth needs indexes on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with a sample of your database to test our solutions please ?

You can try this :

```
select u.user_id, r.role_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, COALESCE(c.email,NULL), o.state_active, ce.name  
from user  
join user_role r on u.user_id = r.user_id
join company c on r.company_id = c.company_id  
join object_state o on u.state_id = o.state_id  
left outer join user_contact uc on u.user_id = uc.user_id and uc.default_flag = 'Y' and uc.status = 'A'  
left outer join contact c on COALESCE(uc.contact_id,-1) = c.contact_id and c.contact_type like 'E%'
```

Here, you should look at the `COALESCE`.